# How can I set ViewPager layoutParams programmatically?

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager

I have the following code but I get an exception

> java.lang.ClassCastException:
> android.support.v4.view.ViewPager$LayoutParams cannot be cast to
> android.view.ViewGroup$MarginLayoutParams

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.question_details_full_photo_view_pager);
    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    ArrayList<String> imageUrls = bundle.getStringArrayList("imageUrls");
    ImagePagerAdapter imagePagerAdapter = new ImagePagerAdapter(this, imageUrls, true);
    
    android.support.v4.view.ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager_full_photo);
    
    
    android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LayoutParams();
    layoutParams.width = LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
    layoutParams.height = LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
    viewPager.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    
    
    viewPager.setAdapter(imagePagerAdapter);
}
```

Comment: What are the imports you're using?

Comment: A quick solution can be (but not necessairly) to set: instead `android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LayoutParams();` -> to `android.support.v4.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LayoutParams();`

Answer (score 7):

You really shouldn't be setting the layout params programmatically just for setting up width and height to "match_parent": this could easily be done using fundamental xml declarations.

If however there's something more advanced you need that you didn't specify - such as adjusting margins or adding views dynamically, consider wrapping the ViewPager with a layout matching your case. For example:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/view_pager_full_photo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

In this case, to adjust margins (for example):

```
ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager_full_photo);
ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams lp = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) pager.getLayoutParams();
lp.topMargin += TOP_MARGIN_HEIGHT_PX;
```

etc.

Note that in this case the **layout params returned by the call to pager.getLayoutParams() are those of the wrapping RelativeLayout** - which could be more easily manipulated to your fit your needs.

Answer (score 3):

This is because you misunderstood the `LayoutParams` in this context : setting the layout params of your ViewPager will layout it out in its parent which is a ViewGroup. You have therefore to pass an instance of `ViewGroup.LayoutParams`.
If you want rather to lay out a component in your ViewPager, you have to set the layout params of the child with an instance of `ViewPager.LayoutParams`

Comment: ViewGroup.layoutParams also throws the same exception. it seems to be expecting android.view.ViewGroup$MarginLayoutParams but there is no such thing

Comment: @code578841441 there is [http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams.html](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams.html)

You need to use the LayoutParam from `ViewPager`'s parent not the `ViewPager` itself. And I just forgot this.. :)

Answer (score 0):

val pager = findViewById(R.id.view_pager);

val params = CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams(CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
params.setMargins(44, 44, 44, 44);
pager.layoutParams = params